# How do I remove directories from Indexing in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I have a large project folder that contains many sub projects. Only 4 are part of the Android project, the rest are C code.

However, it appears that Android Studio is indexing ALL of it, which takes a long time.

How do I exclude these other directories from indexing?

There no way to explicitly do it, and the Module Settings only lists the Android projects so I cannot remove the other folders from there.

Answer (score 26):

1. Select the directory in the Project explorer.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>
3. Search for `Excluded` and hit enter.

Careful, I haven't been able to find a way to 're-include' folders back yet.

Comment: A dirty way to re-include the folder is to edit the parent .iml file and remove the corresponding excludeFolder entry.

Comment: @DavidBurström Don't the `.iml` files get overwritten by Android Studio on each project build? Pretty sure you'll need to remove it from a `build.gradle` file somewhere, which is where the `excludeFolder` entry gets generated from.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter Yes, you're right. I've just posted a new solution that I've used successfully.

Comment: @DavidBurström Good stuff. Same solution I found for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47244842/293280

Answer (score 19):

1. (optional) Switch to project view if you can't see the folders you want to exclude
2. Right click the folder you want to exclude
3. In the contextual menu click *"Mark directory as" --> "Excluded"*
   It should look like this:
   [image: IDE contextual menu]
4. (optional) If you want to include a folder, click *"Mark directory as" --> "Cancel exclusion"*
   [image: Other IDE contextual menu]

Comment: This is simplest solution worked for me. Just make sure to reopen project after excluding directory

Answer (score 9):

Use the `'idea'` plugin to exclude directories. For some reason, it seems the `idea` configuration is ignored if a subproject is configuring it (and will always exclude the `project.buildDir` and `.gradle` folders), but it works if you tell the root project which directories to exclude:

In your root project `build.gradle` file, do

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
  module {
    excludeDirs.add(file('path/to/subproject'))
    excludeDirs.add(file('path/to/othersubproject'))
  }
}
```

After syncing, you'll notice that the root projects `.iml` file contains corresponding `<excludeFolder>` tags, and that Android Studio no longer indexes the directories.

Comment: When you say "anymore", which versions are involved then?

Comment: excludeDirs += works, but excludeDirs.add does not work. This applies to Android Studio 3.5: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58033717/android-studio-how-to-exclude-doc-folder-from-search-and-other-functionality

Comment: This might be a bug of the idea gradle plugin. Does the above snippet still work for you for recent Studio and gradle versions?

Comment: how to exclude a particular file type from indexing?

Answer (score 0):

In the left side project panel, right click the file you want to exclude from indexing, and then select `Mark as Plain Text`.

Answer (score 0):

As there is no "Mark directory as" menu in Android Studio, I found out that such settings like including and excluding directories are stored in a ".iml" file. Named like "project-name.iml".

A line like bellow is used to exclude a dir:

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/x/" />
```

So, Re-including is done as easily as removing the line.

Comment: I've got this setting, I don't know why you haven't.