# How to re-include an excluded directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

It's explained how to exclude a directory in Android Studio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30584701/1664314). It also has a warning about not knowing how to include it back again. Now I need to do so.

Of-course I can create/import the project again. But I guess there's a better way of doing that. Is there? How?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is no "*Mark directory as*" menu in Android Studio, I found out that such settings like including and excluding directories are stored in a "***.iml***" file. Named like "*project-name.iml*".

A line like bellow is used to exclude a dir:

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/blah/blah/blah/" />
```

So, Re-including is done as easily as removing the line.

Answer (score 6):

if you right click an excluded directory in the Project View, you can select from the context menu:

> Mark directory as → Cancel exclusion

Comment: I use android-studio 2.1 and it doesn't have the option "Mark directory as".
should I add it somehow?
Actually I checked it with IntelliJ on another computer and it has the feature. So, my bad. I will edit my question and limit it to just Android Studio. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete .iml file then try to sync and it will work fine