# How do I exclude a directory, like `node_modules` from Android Studio's Open File window?

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

The Open File window in Android Studio, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, will search all directories by default, including the `node_modules` directory. This forces you to have to go through endless common files, like `AndroidManifest.xml`, before finding the one in your root directory.

I noticed that in the `my_project.iml` file there is an `excludeFolder` tag but any edits I make to the `my_project.iml` file get overwritten the next time I rebuild the project.

How do I exclude the `node_modules` directory **permanently** from coming up in the Open File window?

This is on Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove directories from Indexing in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767923/how-do-i-remove-directories-from-indexing-in-android-studio)

Comment: If you are trying to open up react-native android project you can just add the android folder to Android Studio and not the complete react-native project. This way you just see the related files with android in your Android Studio project structure.

Comment: @bennygenel You're definitely right for most cases, however, we've integrated React Native to an existing Android app so there is no `android` directory. We'll probably change that later when we add iOS and Windows support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Add `excludeDirs` in your `build.gradle` file.

As per [Nilzor's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46036948/293280), the right way to do this is by adding the following to your root `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea.module {
    excludeDirs += file('node_modules/')
}
```

Now, rebuild your project and check your `my_project.iml` file. You'll see the new `excludeFolder` entry:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/.gradle" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/node_modules" />
</content>
```