# Exclude build folders from indexing in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

My multi-module app is constantly being indexed during build process.
I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767923/how-do-i-remove-directories-from-indexing-in-android-studio) and excluded build folder from indexing. However, it reappears in indexes in a while. My .iml folder is not in version control, so it is not overwritten by git.
How can I fix that and why does it happen?

Some parameters:

1. Android Studio 3.4
2. Gradle 5.1.1
3. com.android.tools.build:gradle 3.4.0

Comment: Normally, the needed for exclusion directories are already excluded. Are there any generated files inside project not excluded directories (output of scripts, log files etc)? IDE re-index the file on it's change or when new file appears. You can also add `-Dide.showIndexRebuildMessage=true` into Help | Edit Custom VM Options, restart IDE and when issue happens check the log file on records about when have caused the re-index.

Comment: @Andrey I have added the flag, will post update. But maybe it is because of Kotlin/Dagger 2/Butterknife? Those are generating stuff for me and are putting it into build folder.

Comment: I have the same problem: there is a separate build folder that contains build artifacts for multiple platforms, including Android. This folder is not in the source tree, yet somehow Android Studio finds it and spends eternity indexing it. It does not even show the contents of my project.