# Set folders in sibling directory tree to be excluded Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android NDK project that lives in a large repository that is located `/src/project/myandroidproject`.

It requires a couple of libraries that are located in a very large directory `src/libs`. For example, `src/libs/json`.

When including these libraries android studio decides to index the whole `src/libs`, which is a bad idea as this folder is ~100GBs and will cause Android studio to completely freeze and crash when "Updating Symbols".

I have found that I can mark the whole directory as excluded, but this seems to be reset every time I sync the gradle project.
I've found this answer: [How do I remove directories from Indexing in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767923/how-do-i-remove-directories-from-indexing-in-android-studio).
However, this only seems to apply for child directories of the project.

I am looking for a way to be able to exclude a directory from being indexed by Android Studio when that directory is not a child directory of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of referencing the real locations of the projects, which caused Android Studio to try and index all sibling directories, I created symlinks inside my project folder, which then referenced the other projects.